# Strongswan + FreeRADIUS and Windows 10 clients without internet access

Tags: strongswan

I apologise for another query regarding Strongswan. I have created Strongswan server that has on one side multiple networks and on the second side are clients that are authorised via FreeRADIUS EAP-MSCHAPv2. Clients have access rights to specific IP addresses in networks via Class attributes and appropriate connection definitions in ipsec.conf:

```
config setup
   charondebug="all"
   uniqueids=yes
   strictcrlpolicy=no

conn %default
   keyexchange=ikev2

conn tunnel 
   reauth=no
   rightsendcert=never
   left=87.236.194.XX
   leftsubnet=192.168.80.0/24
   right=%any
   rightsubnet=0.0.0.0/0
   keyingtries=0
   ikelifetime=1h
   lifetime=8h
   dpddelay=30
   dpdtimeout=120
   dpdaction=clear
   authby=secret
   auto=route
   type=tunnel

conn eap-radius
    reauth=no
    rekey=no
    forceencaps=yes
    fragmentation=yes
    left=%defaultroute
    leftauth=pubkey
    leftcert=host-vpn.der
    leftsendcert=always
    leftfirewall=yes
    leftsubnet=0.0.0.0/0
    leftid=@ikev2.domain.cz
    lefthostaccess=yes
    right=%any
    rightsourceip=192.168.80.0/24
    rightdns=8.8.8.8
    rightauth=eap-radius
    rightgroups=Class1
    eap_identity=%identity
    auto=add

conn eap-radius10
    reauth=no
    rekey=no
    forceencaps=yes
    fragmentation=yes
    left=%defaultroute
    leftauth=pubkey
    leftcert=host-vpn.der
    leftsendcert=always
    leftfirewall=yes
    leftsubnet=192.168.10.2/31,192.168.10.4/30,192.168.10.8/29,192.168.10.16/28,192.168.10.32/27,192.168.10.64/26,192.168.10.128/26,192.168.10.192/27,192.168.10.224/28,192.168.10.240/29,192.168.10.248/30,192.168.10.252/31,192.168.10.254/32
    leftid=@ikev2.domain.cz
    lefthostaccess=yes
    right=%any
    rightsourceip=192.168.80.0/24
    rightdns=8.8.8.8
    rightauth=eap-radius
    rightgroups=Class10
    eap_identity=%identity
    auto=add

conn eap-radius20
    reauth=no
    rekey=no
    forceencaps=yes
    fragmentation=yes
    left=%defaultroute
    leftauth=pubkey
    leftcert=host-vpn.der
    leftsendcert=always
    leftfirewall=yes
    leftsubnet=192.168.20.2/31,192.168.20.4/30,192.168.20.8/29,192.168.20.16/28,192.168.20.32/27,192.168.20.64/26,192.168.20.128/26,192.168.20.192/27,192.168.20.224/28,192.168.20.240/29,192.168.20.248/30,192.168.20.252/31,192.168.20.254/32
    leftid=@ikev2.domain.cz
    lefthostaccess=yes
    right=%any
    rightsourceip=192.168.80.0/24
    rightdns=8.8.8.8
    rightauth=eap-radius
    rightgroups=Class20
    eap_identity=%identity
    auto=add
```

In Debian firewall I have lines:

```
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.80.0/24 -o eth0 -m policy --dir out --pol ipsec -j ACCEPT
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.80.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

My problem is that all Android, iOS and Mac OSX clients except Windows 10 ones have access to appropriate specific addresses and also to Internet. Because the VPN connection wizard in past versions of Windows 10 due some Microsoft's bugs in this wizard is not able to create the EAP-MSCHAPv2 IKEv2 VPN connection properly I have copied following rasphone.pbk to the C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Network\Connections\Pbk windows folder

```
[radius]
Encoding=1
PBVersion=4
Type=2
AutoLogon=0
UseRasCredentials=1
LowDateTime=-1192997568
HighDateTime=30663332
DialParamsUID=191937
Guid=2F7BD8C93E1B8E4885FD6AB316030199
VpnStrategy=7
ExcludedProtocols=0
LcpExtensions=1
DataEncryption=8
SwCompression=0
NegotiateMultilinkAlways=0
SkipDoubleDialDialog=0
DialMode=0
OverridePref=15
RedialAttempts=3
RedialSeconds=60
IdleDisconnectSeconds=0
RedialOnLinkFailure=1
CallbackMode=0
CustomDialDll=
CustomDialFunc=
CustomRasDialDll=
ForceSecureCompartment=0
DisableIKENameEkuCheck=0
AuthenticateServer=0
ShareMsFilePrint=1
BindMsNetClient=1
SharedPhoneNumbers=0
GlobalDeviceSettings=0
PrerequisiteEntry=
PrerequisitePbk=
PreferredPort=VPN2-0
PreferredDevice=WAN Miniport (IKEv2)
PreferredBps=0
PreferredHwFlow=1
PreferredProtocol=1
PreferredCompression=1
PreferredSpeaker=1
PreferredMdmProtocol=0
PreviewUserPw=0
PreviewDomain=0
PreviewPhoneNumber=0
ShowDialingProgress=0
ShowMonitorIconInTaskBar=0
CustomAuthKey=26
CustomAuthData=314442431A00000008000000010000000000000000000000
AuthRestrictions=128
IpPrioritizeRemote=1
IpInterfaceMetric=0
IpHeaderCompression=0
IpAddress=0.0.0.0
IpDnsAddress=0.0.0.0
IpDns2Address=0.0.0.0
IpWinsAddress=0.0.0.0
IpWins2Address=0.0.0.0
IpAssign=1
IpNameAssign=1
IpDnsFlags=0
IpNBTFlags=1
TcpWindowSize=0
UseFlags=2
IpSecFlags=0
IpDnsSuffix=
Ipv6Assign=1
Ipv6Address=::
Ipv6PrefixLength=0
Ipv6PrioritizeRemote=1
Ipv6InterfaceMetric=0
Ipv6NameAssign=1
Ipv6DnsAddress=::
Ipv6Dns2Address=::
Ipv6Prefix=0000000000000000
Ipv6InterfaceId=0000000000000000
DisableClassBasedDefaultRoute=0
DisableMobility=0
NetworkOutageTime=0
ProvisionType=0
PreSharedKey=
CacheCredentials=1
NumCustomPolicy=0
NumEku=0
UseMachineRootCert=0
NumServers=0
RouteVersion=1
NumRoutes=0
NumNrptRules=0
AutoTiggerCapable=0
NumAppIds=0
NumClassicAppIds=0
SecurityDescriptor=
ApnInfoProviderId=
ApnInfoUsername=
ApnInfoPassword=
ApnInfoAccessPoint=
ApnInfoAuthentication=1
ApnInfoCompression=0
DeviceComplianceEnabled=0
DeviceComplianceSsoEnabled=0
DeviceComplianceSsoEku=
DeviceComplianceSsoIssuer=
FlagsSet=0
Options=0
DisableDefaultDnsSuffixes=0
NumTrustedNetworks=0
NumDnsSearchSuffixes=0
PowershellCreatedProfile=0
ProxyFlags=0
ProxySettingsModified=0
ProvisioningAuthority=
AuthTypeOTP=0
GREKeyDefined=0
NumPerAppTrafficFilters=0
AlwaysOnCapable=0
PrivateNetwork=0

NETCOMPONENTS=
ms_msclient=1
ms_server=1

MEDIA=rastapi
Port=VPN2-0
Device=WAN Miniport (IKEv2)

DEVICE=vpn
PhoneNumber=ikev2.domain.cz
AreaCode=
CountryCode=0
CountryID=0
UseDialingRules=0
Comment=
FriendlyName=
LastSelectedPhone=0
PromoteAlternates=0
TryNextAlternateOnFail=1
```

Such Windows VPN client is able to connect properly to the appropriate IPs in remote networks but has no access to internet with one exception - internet access works when is via RADIUS selected connection definition with leftsubnet=0.0.0.0/0. When the Use default gateway on remote network option in the Advanced TCP/IP settings of the VPN connection is enabled (IpPrioritizeRemote=1) client has access to remote networks but not to internet and if this option is disabled the client has access to internet but not to any of remote networks.

I am not experienced in routing but I suppose it should be possible to configure the windows VPN connection to behave just like the Android, iOS and OSX connections that are working properly and have except access to specific IP addresses also access to internet.

For any help thank you in advance

Comment: Windows has problems with split tunneling. You might have to configure routes for the remote subnets manually, or tunnel everything via VPN. See [ForwardingAndSplitTunneling](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/ForwardingAndSplitTunneling) on the strongSwan wiki. By the way, there are PowerShell cmdlets to manage VPNs (and e.g. configure routes).

Comment: I apologise for bothering you but I am not experienced in routing so, may I ask you for example of solution for example for conn eap-radius10 ? :-)

Comment: Maybe I am not right but I feel that the manual route configuration could work only in the case when from the windows pc will sign up  users from one Class. Would it be possible to manually configure the windows pc for users from all existing Classes?

Comment: Yes, you have to know the subnets that can be routed (it is a manual configuration after all). But if it doesn't cause problems for the users you could also configure all possible subnets (packets for subnets that are then not in _leftsubnet_ for a particular Class should be dropped by the client as they won't be covered by the negotiated IPsec policies, they will definitely be dropped by the server as it strictly enforces the policies).

Answer (score 0):

ecdsa thank you for point me the right direction. The solution was finally quite simple. From PowerShell as administrator I created the new connection:

```
 Add-VpnConnection -Name "radius" -ServerAddress "ikev2.domain.cz" –TunnelType IKEv2 -EncryptionLevel Required -AuthenticationMethod EAP -SplitTunneling –AllUserConnection
```

and then I added routes:

```
Add-VpnConnectionRoute -ConnectionName "radius" -DestinationPrefix 192.168.10.0/24 -PassThru
Add-VpnConnectionRoute -ConnectionName "radius" -DestinationPrefix 192.168.20.0/24 -PassThru
```

Now windows clients are working like a charm and they have access to the appropriate IPs and internet too.